# How to export set of rows depending on date from datatable into multiple sheets of excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I want to export particular rows into multiple sheets of excel depends on date from datatable in vb.net

My code

I want 17/08/2016 in one sheet 18/08/2016 in nextsheet.
My table rows like this:

```
s.no date     
 1    17/08/2016    
 2    17/08/2016    
 3    17/08/2016    
 4    18/08/2016    
 5    18/08/2016
```

```
          For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 2
            If dt.Rows(i).Item("AttDate") = dt.Rows(i + 1).Item("AttDate") Then
                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee) = dt.Rows(i).Item("Intime")
                If dt.Rows(i).Item("latein") > 0 Then
                    oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 1) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                Else
                    oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 2) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                End If
                Irow = Irow + 1
            Else
                osheet1 = oBook.Worksheets(2)

                osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee) = dt.Rows(i).Item("Intime")
                If dt.Rows(i).Item("latein") > 0 Then
                    osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 1) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                Else
                    osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 2) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                End If
                Irow = Irow + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the issue?

Comment: i have set of rows from datatable.in that date column is there..i export different sheets based on date..

Comment: OK... Are you having trouble with exporting to excel?

Comment: I know how to do in single sheet

Comment: Move everything from the "else" part and put it in the main if condition... is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strValue As String
      For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 2
        If i = 0 Then

            ' Sheet 1
            oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

            oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee) = dt.Rows(i).Item("Intime")
            If dt.Rows(i).Item("latein") > 0 Then
                oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 1) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
            Else
                oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 2) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
            End If

            Irow = Irow + 1

        Else

            If dt.Rows(i).Item("AttDate") = strValue then
             ' Sheet 1
                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee) = dt.Rows(i).Item("Intime")
                If dt.Rows(i).Item("latein") > 0 Then
                   oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 1) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                Else
                   oSheet.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 2) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                End If

                Irow = Irow + 1

            Else

                ' Sheet 2
                osheet1 = oBook.Worksheets(2)

                osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee) = dt.Rows(i).Item("Intime")
                If dt.Rows(i).Item("latein") > 0 Then
                    osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 1) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                Else
                    osheet1.Cells(Irow, IcolFranchisee + 2) = dt.Rows(i).Item("latein")
                End If

            End If

            Irow = Irow + 1

        End If

        strValue = dt.Rows(i).Item("AttDate")

    Next
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If yes what is the error? If not, what is the output?

Comment: in first sheet itself all coming.second sheet only one row

Comment: Put a break point and check the steps and values. Can you provide a screenshot of the output?

Comment: can u provide mail id..i wil send file itself

Comment: Edit the question and put a screenshot, can't provide email sorry:-(

Comment: ok that image does not correlate to the condition used in the 'if', can you provide the screenshot of the datatable?

Comment: They all are the same date, I did not see any entry with a different date. Please check the data you are passing in.

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Put breakpoints within code and find out what is going on.